What is this component? (datasheet)
I can't find the datasheet online.

The component is mounted in the circuit of a Bluetooth speaker

It's a  a Jieli (杰理芯片) Bluetooth MCU, probably a AC6965E.

I think it's a AC6965E, because the marking characters after the dash seem to match with the last characters of the product number on Jieli ICs (see this question for an example). The number of pins and the package match as well.
